# Дефис или апостроф на стыке латиницы и кириллицы: сложные случаи

Tags: заимствования, дефис, сложные-слова, латиница-кириллица, апостроф

Как писать слова, образованные присоединением русскоязычных элементов к отдельным буквам или аббревиатурам, написанным кириллицей? Как то:

- *S-очка* ("эсочка", размер одежды);
- *IT-шник* ("айтишник", категория профессий);
- *USA-щик* ("юэсэйщик", сленговое название сторонников образа жизни и политики США) и др.

С одной стороны, существует правило дефисного написания (см. [Грамоту.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=286438)):

> Дефис употребляется в составе письменных эквивалентов сложных слов, часть которых передается цифрой, буквой или буквами (в том числе нерусского алфавита) или иным начертанием (даже таким, которое невозможно «прочесть»), напр.: *25-процентный*, *150-летие*, *300-миллионный*, *5 1/2-тысячный*, *Т-образный*, *IBM-совместимый*, *γ-активный*, «*S-образное движение ловкого тела*» (Купр.), *ww-образные трубки*.

С другой стороны, есть правило написания через апостроф, когда это касается русскоязычных окончаний и суффиксов (см. [Грамоту.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=298236)):

> Русские окончания и суффиксы отделяются апострофом от предшествующей части слова, передаваемой латинскими буквами.

Как быть в таких случаях? Подчеркну, что это, конечно, можно передать кириллицей ("эсочка", "айтишник" и т. д.), но как быть именно со стыковкой, как она оформляется в подобных ситуациях?

**ДОПОЛНЕНО (16.12.2022)**

"Грамота.ру" наконец ответила (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=309701)):

> Действует такое правило: апострофом отделяются русские окончания и суффиксы от предшествующей части слова, передаваемой латинскими буквами. Таким образом, корректно: *IT'шник*, *S'очка*. Но эти слова лучше всё же писать кириллицей, поскольку они уже вошли в русский язык.

Comment: Ссылаясь на Грамоту, лучше давать ссылку на конкретный вопрос, а не на поиск по слову. То есть должно быть не **http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84**, а **http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=289040**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правило про апостроф гласит: *Русские **окончания и суффиксы** отделяются апострофом...* В словах *Т-образный, IBM-совместимый, γ-активный* используются отнюдь не только русские окончания и суффиксы, поэтому правило про апостроф тут неприменимо, а применяется правило про дефис.

Правильно писать: *S’очка, IT’шник, USA’щик*